# Como criar grupos em regex para validar critérios senha em Elixir?

Tags: regex, elixir

Eu preciso validar os critérios em uma senha:

- Deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.
- Pelo menos uma minúscula
- Pelo menos um número
- O tamanho deve estar entre 6 e 32 caracteres
- Não pode ter nenhum carácter especial ou espaço
- Deve ter todos os 3 tipos: maiúsculas, minúsculas e números, não importa a ordem

Eu tentei várias maneiras, dei uma olhada na documentação de regex (Elixir e Perl), mas travei aqui:

`Regex.run(~r/^[A-Z](?=.*)[a-z](?=.*)[^\W_]{5,30}$/,IO.gets"")`

Mas esta regex só permite a senha começando com maiúsculas e não permite números, se eu adicionar algo como `\d(?=.*)` ou `[0-9](?=.*)` nada mais funciona.

Como exemplo em ES/JS seria: `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[^\W_]{6,32}$/`

Comment: Esse exemplo em Js está correto. Isso é uma pergunta ou uma resposta?

Comment: O exemplo em JS está correto, funciona para todos os critérios e independente da ordem dos itens. É uma pergunta, corrigi o título.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para criar a expressão procurada, você deve usar os Positive Lookaheads (`(?=...)`), como já deve ter percebido. Porém, você está usando-o de modo incorreto. Para adicionar critérios sem uma ordem específica, seus lookaheads devem estar presentes antes do texto validado.

**Exemplo 1:**

```
/(?=a).../
Corresponde com:
abc, acb
Não corresponde com:
bca, cba
```

Com isso em mente, para fazer o lugar que a letra `a` aparece ser irrelevante, adicione `.*` antes e depois do critério procurado.

**Exemplo 2:**

```
/(?=.*a.*).../
Corresponde com:
abc, acb, bca, cba
```

Agora só resta adicionar outros grupos com os critérios necessários, sendo eles:

`(?=.*[a-z].*)` - Requer ao menos uma letra minúscula

`(?=.*[A-Z].*)` - Requer ao menos uma letra maiúscula

`(?=.*[0-9].*)` - Requer ao menos um número

E o resto necessário para combinar:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}` - de 6 à 32 caracteres válidos para sua senha (no qual também pode ser reduzido para: `(?:\w|\d){6,32}`).

Aqui está sua expressão completa:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$/
```

Confira os resultados [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8woFmn/2).